# fast access to a matrix by row and column key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have such a matrix

```
id = (123, 979, 234)

 matrix: 

    123  979  234
123  0   30    45
979  30   0    60
234  15   45    0
```

My problem is, I want to access a matrix in a fast and easy way. Something like this:

matrix[id][id]

example:

print(matrix[123][979])

output 30

For now I'm using a list including a list. So I can access the data by knowing the position. This is not very comfortable, because I don't know the position, I just know the id. For now I am using a function which gives me the right number. This is very slow and I need this for a calculation with many iterations.

Does anybody has an idea to solve this in a fast way?

The function to calculate the matrix for now is this below, but it is just zero or 30*60 seconds. I want to create a new matrix with individual times, but before coding it, I want to figure out, in which way I can store the data to have fast and easy access.

```
def get_matrix(permutation):

criteria = [django_model1.objects.filter(id=id).get().django_model2.format for id in permutation]

# and to speed up: an ugly combination of 2 list comprehensions and a lambda function. 
return [[(lambda c1, c2: timedelta(seconds = 0 ) if c1==c2 else timedelta(seconds = 30*60 )) (c1,c2) for c2 in criteria] for c1 in criteria ]
```

Comment: give an example of what you are accessing. a number? a list of numbers?

Comment: does this edit help?

Comment: sure. so if it is a numpy array or a pandas dataframe? can you share the code to create the 'matrix'?

Comment: well, I am using  just normal lists. but wait a moment, I will make an example...

Comment: done... I hope it is not too confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas`:

```
data = [[0, 30, 45], [30, 0, 60], [15, 45, 0]]
ids = [123, 979, 234]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ids, index = ids)
```

`data` can be constructed in a lot of ways: depends on how you're constructing your matrix. Refer to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for more info.

Now, refer by id:

```
>>> df[979][123]
30
```

**Note:** The order of ids is reversed since `pandas` takes the column id as the first index.

Comment: it's so fantastic!!! I got a speedup from 1:43 min to 9 sec. just by accessing the data like this instead of calling a function.